# How to get Meteor.Call to return value for template?

Tags: callback, meteor

I've tried [to understand this post regarding this concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379445/how-to-get-the-result-of-a-meteor-call-function-in-a-template), however, I'm failing to get it. I have the following simple setup:

```
/server/test.js
Meteor.methods({ 
  abc: function() {
    var result = {};
    result.foo = "Hello ";
    result.bar = "World!";
    return result;
  }
});

/client/myapp.js
var q = Meteor.call('abc');
console.log(q);
```

This structure returns to the console `undefined`.

If I change the `myapp.js` file to:

```
Meteor.call('abc', function(err, data) {
  !err ? console.log(data) : console.log(err);
}
```

I receive the `Object` in my console.

Ideally this is what I'd like to be able to do, but it doesn't work, stating in the console: `Cannot read property 'greeting' of undefined`

```
/client/myapp.js
var q = Meteor.call('abc');

Template.hello.greeting = function() {
   return q.foo;
}
```

Any help in passing the data from the server object into the template would be greatly appreciated. I'm still learning JavaScript & Meteor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

From [the `Meteor.call` documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call):

> On the client, if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a stub, call will return undefined, and you will have no way to get the return value of the method. That is because the client doesn't have fibers, so there is not actually any way it can block on the remote execution of a method.

So, you'll want to do it like this:

```
Meteor.call('abc', function(err, data) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);

  Session.set('q', data);
});

Template.hello.greeting = function() {
  return Session.get('q').foo;
};
```

This will reactively update the template once the data is available.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks so much for your quick response! I had to close your Meteor.call function with `);` and append a semi-colon at the end of the `Template.hello.greeting` function to get it to finally work (if you wanted to edit your code). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hi Tom, quick question - if the data isn't expected to change at all long term, is there a way to do without having to use the session object? Seems very wasteful and verbose otherwise, as the number of variables increases. Thank you.

Comment: You could perhaps try Amplify to access localStorage.

Comment: For a meteor beginner it seems odd that for templates, which by nature are dynamic, one should have to shuffle data via sessions... Is this truly the best way to do this?

Comment: @kontur: It might be possible to redefine the Template.hello.greeting function. In comparison, the session allows reuse.

Comment: You can also use `ReactiveVar` instead of the `Session`, either way this still isn't reactive since it relies on calling `Meteor.call`.  I'm searching for a way to get a server var from a Meteor method reactively to the client.

Comment: This is not correct. Session does not appear on the server side.

Comment: @ThaiTran: It is correct, the abc function is on the server side.

Comment: Is this answer no longer true? I am calling my method with a callback and it always returns a result `undefined`. It's not erroring out either, I checked that already.

Comment: @kontur the Meteor way to do this is not Method calls, it's subscriptions. Methods are closer to "remote procedure calls".

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `Npm.require` has Async behavior. That's the reason that you have to write a callback for `Meteor.call`.

But there is a solution, just use `install(mrt add npm)` and you'll get a function named `Meteor.sync(//...)` with this you can do both games: sync and async in your `Meteor.call()`.

Reference: http://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-meteor-app-using-npm-module/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the return value of a Meteor method for use in a template by using a [reactive variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar). Check out the [working demonstration on Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/SgZcFbpXXSRDLqRD2/MethodTest)

Comment: The example in Meteorpad doesn't work for me. Also, deploying the example works... sort of. That is, it works once, but, for me, the method isn't called when the underlying information is updated.

Comment: Methods are not themselves reactive, but can be called from within a reactive context such as Template.instance().autorun() or template helpers.

Answer (score 0):

I went for a ghetto solution. But, it works for me, which is what matters, to me. Below is my code, which, in concept, I think, solves OP's problem.

In the client's main.js:

```
Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    confirmLogin();

}, 5000);
```

This runs the confirmLogin() function every five seconds.

The confirmLogin function (in the client's main.js):

```
function confirmLogin() {
    Meteor.call('loggedIn', function (error, result) {
        Session.set("loggedIn", result);
    });

}
```

The loggedIn method (in the server's main.js):

```
loggedIn: function () {
    var toReturn = false;
    var userDetails = Meteor.user();
    if (typeof userDetails["services"] !== "undefined") {
        if (typeof userDetails["services"]["facebook"] != "undefined") {
            toReturn = true;
        }
    }

    return toReturn;
},
```

The relevant helper:

```
loggedIn: function () {
    return Session.get("loggedIn");
}
```