# How to render HTML of Meteor Session variable?

Tags: html, meteor

Further to [my previous post about obtaining data from objects on the server using Meteor.call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677491/how-to-get-meteor-call-to-return-value-for-template) I'd like to know how this same data can render HTML once similar object data from the server is received. Here is a simple example:

```
/server/svr.js
Meteor.methods({
  test: function(text) {
    var result = {};
    result.foo = "<em>" + text + "</em>";
    result.bar = text;
    return result;
  }
});

/client/del.js
Meteor.call('test', "Hello World - May 2012", function(err, data) {
if (err)
  console.log(err);

  Session.set('q', data);
});

Template.hello.greeting = function() {
  return Session.get('q').foo;
};
```

When I run this code in the standard meteor app I see on the browser window:

```
Hello World!
<em>Hello World - May 2012</em>
```

Ideally I'd like the session variable containing the html code to have rendered that which was passed into it (in the simple example above - making the second line italicised when output to the browser). How do I go about accomplishing this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Having the server return markup is odd.  Why not have the `<em>` tag in the `hello` template?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `{{{greeting}}}` instead of `{{greeting}}` to make sure it isn't escaped.