# #each loop {{this }} not getting populated

Tags: templates, meteor, each

I'm stuck so any help really appreciated. I've tried lots of things - new to meteor and can't get the `#each` in template hand to show anything

See my meteorpad http://meteorpad.com/pad/FqMJWySAMZGcyaTf6 or see code below.

```html
<template name="player">
    <div>{{_id}}</div>
    <div class="name">{{name}}</div>
    <div class="score">{{score}}</div>
    <div>{{>cards  hand}}</div>
</template>

<template name="cards">
<div>
{{#each hand}}
    <span>{{this}}</span>
{{/each}}
</div>
</template>
```

On client - response is showing correctly in console.log below:

```javascript
Template.cards.hand = function(){
    if (Players.find().count() > 0 )
    {
    Meteor.call("deal", playerNum,function(err,response){
        if(err){
          console.log("error dealing: " + err);
        }
        console.log("in player hand" + response);

        return response;

    });
    }
  };
```

Comment: Where do you get playerNum?

Comment: The `Meteor.call` on the client is implemented internally as an `AJAX` operation, that's why it takes a call back `function(err,response)` to call later when the operation is complete.  But that won't return anything to `Template.cards.hand()`, as the operation is merely queued `Template.cards.hand()` will return immediately with no data.

Comment: @Paul Asynchronous, but not AJAX. Meteor method calls use DDP (just like subscriptions).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Meteor.Call to return value for template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677491/how-to-get-meteor-call-to-return-value-for-template)

Comment: @Neil Fine, but similar limitations.

Comment: I think one way to solve the issue is to have the hand stored in a session variable, and use the callback to Meteor.call update that session variable, which would trigger a redraw of a template if the template read from there.  This involves restructuring more code than has been revealed.

Comment: maybe this is helpful https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-ddp-analyzer

Comment: Thanks everyone - missed seeing answers til now - thought I set up email notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you return a function, which cannot be a parameter of `#each` (note the console warning: `Uncaught Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.`).

`#each` can only iterate on `arrays` or `Cursor`s returned by `meteorCollection.find`

So instead of returning the function `Alphas1` you should return:

```
return Alphas1(); // which in turn returns Alphas
```

or directly:

```
return Alphas;
```

#### [See updated example](http://meteorpad.com/pad/rNosATksiH4XYgmFN)